# Remove user entities on module uninstall

Tags: 7, entities

I am using the following code to delete all the nodes and clean up on uninstall of my custom module. How can I do the same thing for my user entity?

```
    function wl_project_uninstall() {
  $sql = 'SELECT nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = :type';
  $result = db_query($sql, array(
    ':type' => 'wl_project'
  ));
  $nids = array();
  foreach ($result as $row) {
    $nids[] = $row->nid;
  }
  node_delete_multiple($nids);
  foreach (array_keys(_wl_project_fields()) as $field) {
    field_delete_field($field);
  }
  node_type_delete('project');
  // Purge all field information
  // http://api.drupal.org/api/function/field_purge_batch/7
  field_purge_batch(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load all user uid's and call [user_delete](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_delete/7)

Comment: user_delete is for Deleting users but does not handle entity fields.

Comment: May be fields those do not have user_delete hook implemented.